# Shopify checkout: zip code verification and amex

Tags: shopify, creditcard

It seems zip code verification against the user's billing address does not work with AMEX. The check works as expected with Mastercard and Visa numbers. Unclear if this is expected as Shopify provides some disclaimer language "If the bank card provider does not support AVS or CVV check, the card will be authorized and the order will be completed" but I would think Amex would be common enough where this is supported.

Comment: Have you approached Amex?

Comment: It seems like an issue with Shopify not Amex ... trying to confirm.